# Rails 5.1, recurring events that user can create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, ruby-on-rails-5, recurring-events

I'm looking for a solution so my users would be able to create recurring events. For example lets say that a user wants to add a post every month on a specific date. Every month on that date a new post would be automatically created with some settings the user will give (title, content etc...)

My app will be pushed on heroku after, I know that heroku handle cron jobs by himslef, is there any option or gem that exist to do that ?

I checked the whenever gem but it's not working with heroku.

EDIT : I bring more infos about what I'm looking for exactly. A user create a post, below this new form I'd like to add a recurring option with a recurrence to select. Every month, week, day. Once the post is created, if the post is recurrent, then the same post is created again according to the selection the user made. The post will be created again and again until the user update the post and stop the recurrence or delete the post.

Comment: And you already tried the heroku scheduler? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Comment: No, not yet. But it may be a stupid question, can you try it on dev first ?

Answer (score 0):

You could give resque-delayed a try
https://github.com/elucid/resque-delayed/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Looks ok to delay a task, but not to be able to create it every month or day

Answer (score 0):

In the current project I use [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler)

It can be configured to run a task like:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.cron '5 0 * * *' do
  # do something every day, five minutes after midnight
  # (see "man 5 crontab" in your terminal)
end
```

You can use https://crontab.guru/ to check the cron scheduler expression.

**OR**

You can take a look on [heroku scheduled jobs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes#custom-clock-processes)